# How to analyse the data files after reading multiple files in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to make a loop in R. Loading the files works, but now I want to use the different datafiles and analyse them.  I'd like to do this in the same loop. It has to be something like:

```
setwd("d:/myRfiles/") 

files <- list.files()       
numfiles <- length(files)     

for (i in 1:numfiles)     
{    
  name<-paste("",files[i],sep="")    
  assign(name, read.csv(files[i],header=FALSE))      
  # So far so good     
  dim(dataset)  
  head(dataset)    
  tail(dataset)   
}
```

I can't use "name" for the dataset cause it reads it as a value.

Thank you.

Comment: The reverse operation to `assign` is `get`, so you can try `dim(get(name))`, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use read.delim, assign data set to it. It's working fine for me.Now use any operation to your file i.e., dataset. For name you can use it as.character or assign the same name to dataset for clarity

```
setwd("") 

files <- list.files()       
numfiles <- length(files)     

for (i in 1:numfiles) {    
  name <- as.character(paste("", files[i], sep="")   ) 
  dataset <- assign(name, read.delim(files[i], header=FALSE))  
  k <- as.character(name)
  k <- dataset

  dim(k)  
  head(k)    
  tail(k)   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would `sapply` through your vector of files.

```
sapply(files, FUN = function(x) {
      data.in <- read.csv(x, header = FALSE)
      # further analysis
   })
```